# WebControls From TextBox - Not Saving New Property on Postaback

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net-2010, web-controls

I am feeling myself an idiot, it should be that simple but it seems it is not working.
Below is my control code.

```
Imports System.Web.UI.WebControls

Public Class PasswordTextBox
            Inherits TextBox
Public Sub New()
    TextMode = TextBoxMode.Password
End Sub

Public Property Password As String
    Get
        Dim s As String = CType(ViewState("Password"), String)
        If s Is Nothing Then Return ""
        Return s
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        ViewState("Password") = value
    End Set
End Property

Private Const DEFAULT_PASSWORD As String = "********************"
Public Overrides Property Text() As String
    Get
        If Password = "" Then Return ""
        Return DEFAULT_PASSWORD
    End Get
    Set
        MyBase.Text = DEFAULT_PASSWORD
        Attributes("value") = DEFAULT_PASSWORD
    End Set
End Property

Protected Overrides Sub OnPreRender(e As EventArgs)
    MyBase.OnPreRender(e)

    Attributes("value") = Text
End Sub
Protected Overrides Sub Render(ByVal output As System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter)
    MyBase.Render(output)
End Sub
```

End Class

the purpose is simple, to overwrite the property to always show ***** as the value and instead use new property Password to get/set the data. So that when user use "Inspect element" feature from browsers, he can't get the actual password.

However, on page post back, when I get txtPassword.Password property, it returns an empty string.

Is there something I am missing? 
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I Was able to find the issue. I had to inherit from IPostBackDataHandler and then override LoadPostData  method.

the new class is like below.

```
Imports System.Web.UI
Imports System.Web.UI.WebControls


Public Class PasswordTextBox
      Inherits TextBox
      Implements IPostBackDataHandler

Public Sub New()
    TextMode = TextBoxMode.Password
End Sub

Public Property Password As String
    Get
        Dim s As String = CType(ViewState("Password"), String)
        If s Is Nothing Then Return ""
        Return s
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        ViewState("Password") = value
    End Set
End Property

Private Const DEFAULT_PASSWORD As String = "********************"
Public Overrides Property Text() As String
    Get
        If Password = "" Then Return ""
        Return DEFAULT_PASSWORD
    End Get
    Set
        MyBase.Text = DEFAULT_PASSWORD
        Attributes("value") = DEFAULT_PASSWORD
    End Set
End Property

Protected Overrides Sub OnPreRender(e As EventArgs)
    MyBase.OnPreRender(e)

    Attributes("value") = Text
End Sub
Protected Overrides Sub Render(ByVal output As System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter)
    MyBase.Render(output)
End Sub

Public Overridable Shadows Function LoadPostData(postDataKey As String, postCollection As System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection) As Boolean Implements IPostBackDataHandler.LoadPostData
    Dim presentValue As String = Password
    Dim postedValue As String = postCollection(postDataKey)

    If presentValue Is Nothing OrElse Not presentValue.Equals(postedValue) Then
        If postedValue <> DEFAULT_PASSWORD Then Password = postedValue
        Return True
    End If

    Return False
End Function

End Class
```